# Matrix of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the standard inner product. Let $W$ be the plane spanned by $(1,1,1)$ and $(1,1,-2)$. Let $U$ be the linear operator defined as: $U$ is rotation through the angle $\theta$, about the straight line through the origin which is orthogonal to $W$. How to find the matrix of $U$ in the standard ordered basis.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$. The rotation axis is the plane normal, which is just a normalized cross product:
$$\vec{a}=\frac{\vec{u}\times\vec{v}}{||\vec{u}\times\vec{v}||}$$
Now use the Rodriguez formula to get the rotation about an arbitrary axis:

$$R_{ij}=\cos\theta \delta_{ij}+(1-\cos\theta) a_i a_j+\sin\theta\epsilon_{ijk}a_k$$

---

Edit:

Your "basis" can be constructed from $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{a}=\vec{u}\times\vec{v}$. Fortunately, $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are already orthogonal, so you simply need to normalize all of them. That way, you can construct the matrix for the change of basis consists of these three columns.
$$P=\begin{bmatrix}\hat{u} &\hat{v}&\hat{a}\end{bmatrix}$$
The rotation matrix you want is
$$R=PZP^T$$
where $Z$ is the rotation matrix around the $z$ axis for angle $\theta$.

Comment: Sir, could you please tell me some solution using change of basis, using more linear algebra rather than a formula.

Answer (score 0):

the vectors in the plane $[1\ 1\ 1]^T,\ [1\ 1\ -2]^T$ are orthogonal. you can find an orthogonal vector to these two, i.e. to plane by finding a vector in the kernel made
up these vectors as rows or through projection. you find that $[1\ -1\ 0]$ is such a vector. now make all these orthogonal vectors to become unit vectors by dividing by their lengths. form a matrix $Q$ made up these orthonormal vectors. the rotation by
$\theta$ in this basis is $ B = \left( \begin{array}{lll} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta & 0 \cr \sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$

now, you do change of basis using $Q = \left( \begin{array}{lll}1/\sqrt 3 & 1 \sqrt 6 & 1\cr 1\sqrt 3 & 1 \sqrt 6 & -1\cr 1\sqrt 3 & -2/\sqrt 6 & 0 \end{array} \right)$
to find the rotation matrix $A = Q^T B Q$ in the standard basis.

hope i did not mess up any computation.